# Missing Hyper V

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v

Laptop with Win 8.1.
Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone
Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51641

Problem: emulator requires hyper-v. needs win 8 pro.
How can I run WP projects with above os and software?

Answer (score 2):

Simple. One easy step.

- Install Windows 8.1 pro.

Finished. Hyper-V is now available as component.